# Compare two dictionary keys using linq query in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How do you compare two dictionary keys using linq query? Below is the code I am currently using in my program:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> sourceProject in sourceProjects)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> targetProject in targetProjects)
    {
        if (targetProject.Key == sourceProject.Key)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need to use Linq, what is wrong with this code? Linq might 'save' you a line of code, but it will almost always be less efficient in terms of allocation and thus performance.

Comment: The quick & dirty solution would be : `sourceProjects.Keys.Intersect(targetProjects.Keys)` but it would do essentially the same thing - iterate over both keys. What are you trying to do? How frequent is it going to be? You could use a HashSet or SortedSet to speed up the operation but you'd still pay to load that HashSet or SortedSet from the original dictionary.

Comment: A somewhat better one-liner would be `sourceProjects.Keys.Where(key=>target.ContainsKey(key))`. This would still iterate over the source, unlike the `xxxSet` classes that take advantage of key hashes

Comment: The reason why I want to use linq query is because I want to optimise the code as much as possible. In addition I plan to use a similar method to compare folders within each project.

Comment: `//do something` is that some kind of projection, conversion or it is a method which has side effect like logging for example?

Comment: I bet the traversing of the projects is not the bottleneck. Besides, you usually don't get any execution time speed-up by using LINQ, on the contrary using LINQ usually slows the code down. You can gain some optimization by using the fact the dictionary key lookup is O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
from kv1 in sourceProjects
join kv2 in targetProjects on kv1.Key equals kv2.Key
select /* whatever, e. g. */ kv1.Value + kv2.Value
```

But actually more efficient would be this:

```
from key in sourceProjects.Keys.Intersect(targetProjects.Keys)
select /* whatever, e. g. */ sourceProjects[key] + targetProjects[key]
```

or maybe

```
from key in sourceProjects.Keys.Intersect(targetProjects.Keys)
let sourceProject = sourceProjects[key]
let targetProject = targetProjects[key]
select /* whatever, e. g. */ sourceProject + targetProject;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> one;
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> two;

    var duplicates = one.Select(o => o.Key).Where(k => two.Select(t => t.Key).Any(kTwo => kTwo == k));
    foreach (var duplicateKey in duplicates)
    {
        // Do whatewer you want with those keys here
    }
```